# WEKA: Plotting the Weighted threshold Curve

Tags: java, classification, weka

Given an evaluation result you can plot the area under ROC-Curve for a certain class.

I am more interested in the overall-performance of my classifier.

WEKA provides only the weighted (averaged over all classes) area under ROC as a single double value.

Is there a possibility to generate a plot of the ROC-Curve summarized over all target classes either via GUI or programmatically (java)?

If not, (how) can I compute it by hand? I read a  bit about area under ROC but I don't know how to obtain the (x,y)-pairs. (Plotting of graphs is allready realized.)

Comment: Weka can be used as an API, there are examples that can be interesting for you http://weka.wikispaces.com/Visualizing+ROC+curve or this http://weka.wikispaces.com/file/detail/VisualizeMultipleROC.java

Comment: Thank you. I will try it tomorrow. But it looks like you also have to define a single class label there.. If the "raw-data" of the threshold-curve is stored in the arff-file (the values for x and y) it might be no problem to calculate an average..